# Positioning button in SwiperJs in react

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I am looking for ways to position the navigation buttons shown in this [demo](https://swiperjs.com/demos#navigation) such that the buttons are on the outside of the swiper component like shown in the image below. Does any know how to do this?
[image]

Comment: Its not clear, do you want to code it without using swiper.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **onSwiper** prop to get your swiper instance and save it with **useState** hook. With that you can do whatever you like according to swiper api. Have fun with coding.

```
export default function App() {
  const [swiperRef, setSwiperRef] = useState(null);

  const prevHandler = () => {
    swiperRef.slidePrev();
  };

  const nextHandler = () => {
    swiperRef.slideNext();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={prevHandler}>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={nextHandler}>Next</button>
      <Swiper spaceBetween={50} onSwiper={(swiper) => setSwiperRef(swiper)}>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```